# How to use commands.js returned value in test.cy.js file

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I am accessing my Gmail account by command `loginByGoogleApi` under commands.js, then getting the requested email body and pulling the required data from the body, and saving it in a const variable `code` >> now I want to .type the pulled email data (code) in my testFile.cy.js.

commands.js

```
/// <reference types="cypress" 
import { parseString } from "xml2js";
Cypress.Commands.add('loginByGoogleApi', () => {  
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    body: {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      client_id:  Cypress.env('googleClientId'),
      client_secret:  Cypress.env('googleClientSecret'),
      refresh_token:  Cypress.env('googleRefreshToken'),
    },   
  }).then(({ body }) => {
    const { access_token, id_token } = body
    cy.log('Opening emails including code to verify')
    cy.request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/verifyCode',
      headers: { Authorization: Bearer ${access_token} },
    }).then(({ body }) => {
      parseString(body, function (err, results) {
        let data = JSON.stringify(results)
        let codeTitle = JSON.parse(data).feed.entry[0].title[0];
        let code = codeTitle.replace('Chaine confirmation code: ','');
        cy.log(code)
      });
    });   
  })
})
```

testFile.cy.js

```
const { Code } = require("@chaine/keychaine");


describe('Open login page', () => {   
  it('Enter your email to login', () => {
    cy.visit('https://chaineapp.com/staging/login%27)
    cy.get('#field-1').click().type('paras@loadtap.com');
    cy.get('[class*="chakra-button css-yg51i0"]').click();
    cy.get('#pin-input-2-0').type(<need to put code here>);
    })   
  it('get code', () => {
    cy.loginByGoogleApi()

  }) 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cy.wrap(code)`, something like this:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress"
import {parseString} from 'xml2js'
Cypress.Commands.add('loginByGoogleApi', () => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    body: {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      client_id: Cypress.env('googleClientId'),
      client_secret: Cypress.env('googleClientSecret'),
      refresh_token: Cypress.env('googleRefreshToken'),
    },
  }).then(({body}) => {
    const {access_token, id_token} = body
    cy.log('Opening emails including code to verify')
    cy.request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/verifyCode',
      headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`},
    }).then(({body}) => {
      parseString(body, function (err, results) {
        let data = JSON.stringify(results)
        let codeTitle = JSON.parse(data).feed.entry[0].title[0]
        let code = codeTitle.replace('Chaine confirmation code: ', '')
        return cy.wrap(code)
      })
    })
  })
})
```

In your test file, it will be like this:

```js
describe('Open login page', () => {
  it('Enter your email to login', () => {
    cy.visit('https://chaineapp.com/staging/login%27')
    cy.get('#field-1').click().type('paras@loadtap.com')
    cy.get('[class*="chakra-button css-yg51i0"]').click()
    cy.loginByGoogleApi().then((code) => {
      cy.get('#pin-input-2-0').type(code) //types code
    })
  })

  it('get code', () => {
    cy.loginByGoogleApi().then((code) => {
      cy.log(code) //logs code
    })
  })
})
```

You can also use the `Cypress.env` to globally save and get the value.

To save you can write:

```js
Cypress.env('code', code)
```

To get the value

```js
cy.get('#pin-input-2-0').type(Cypress.env('code'));
```